# How to use VOID variable in SASS

Tags: css, sass

Hello World :)

I'm trying to write MIXINS for BOX-SHADOW property using SASS like code below.

```
@mixin simpleBoxShadow ($inset, $xoffset, $yoffset, $blur, $spread, $color ) {
    -webkit-box-shadow: $inset $xoffset $yoffset $blur $spread $color;
            box-shadow: $inset $xoffset $yoffset $blur $spread $color;
    ...
}
```

And I'm stucked with INSET value. Sometimes it should be INSET, sometimes just void.
What should I write when I'm using this MIXIN?

```
@include simpleBoxShadow ( -what's there?- , 10px, 10px, 10px, 10px, #000000 );
```

Or how can I do it another way?

Comment: Okey, this will be like that:  

    `@mixin simpleBoxShadow ($string ) {  
        -webkit-box-shadow: $string;  
            box-shadow: $string;  
    ...
    }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Those space-separated values are considered [lists](http://sass-lang.com/docs/yardoc/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html#lists) in SASS. You can use the [join()](http://sass-lang.com/docs/yardoc/Sass/Script/Functions.html#join-instance_method) function to join lists together. So one approach would be to do something like this:

```
@mixin simpleBoxShadow ( $xoffset, $yoffset, $blur, $spread, $color, $inset: false ) {
    $shadow: $xoffset $yoffset $blur $spread $color;

    @if ($inset) {
        $shadow: join(inset, $shadow, space);
    }

    -webkit-box-shadow: $shadow;
            box-shadow: $shadow;
}
```

Then you can use your mixin like this:

```
// with inset
@include simpleBoxShadow( $inset: true, 10px, 10px, 10px, 10px, #000000 );
// without inset
@include simpleBoxShadow( 10px, 10px, 10px, 10px, #000000 );
```

**UPDATE:** you might also want to consider using [Compass](http://compass-style.org/) - it's a framework built on top of SASS that provides lots of convenience functions and mixins, including some for [box-shadow](http://compass-style.org/reference/compass/css3/box_shadow/).